# float input to the right on the same line as an element

Tags: html, css, angular

I have the bellow Angular code where I want some text at the beginning of my column and then an input on the right of my page, all on the same line.

My problem is that the following code floats the input to the right but doesn't keep everything everything on the same line.

```
<div class="row pt-5">
  <div class="col-4">Stuff</div>
  <div class="col-1">Stuff</div>
  <div class="col-7">
    <h3 class="text-danger">Some Text!</h3>
    <div style="float:right">
      <input type="text"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

I read online that it is bad practice to nest row classes so I decided to not go that road. I also tried putting everything inside a input-group and that made everything be in one line but I can't seem to float the input to the right.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, an `input` does not take a closing tag. Everything is contained within. As for your question, you can use a clear fix to `clear:both`, or you can use `flexbox` or `display:inline-block` to solve this pretty easily. Consider the below:

Using a clear fix and floats:

https://jsfiddle.net/yLb5k3mj/2/

```
 <div class="another-div">
   <h3 class="some-text">Some more text!</h3>
   <input class="input2" placeholder="some input" />
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>

.some-text {
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.input2 {
  float:right;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.clearfix {
  clear:both;
}
```

Using inline block display:

https://jsfiddle.net/k5rc8s92/2/

```
<h3 class="text-danger">Some Text!</h3>
<div class="some-div">
<label>input:</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>

h3 {
  display:inline-block;
  width:40%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:left;
}
div {
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:right;
}
input {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

`inline-block` display allows elements to be positioned on the same line, whereas `block` level display means each element will take up its entire line. Using a `float` property is a way around this, but its an outdated and messy one compared to `inline-block` or `flexbox`. Furthermore, try to avoid inline style as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there a way I can do it without specifying the width of each? I'm doing this inline as I don't want to introduce any css files to my project so i would like the least amount of styles.

Comment: @DaveD Why don't you want to specify width? Without a specified width, your elements' default width will be the width of their content within. In that case you'll need to use floats. Also, you don't need to introduce an external css file, just put your css in the `<head>` inside a `<style>` tag.

Comment: I see! could you show an example with floats? Also adding the css in a `<style>` seems too hacky for me, I prefer doing my styling inline.

Comment: @daveD the answer has been updated to show you with a clearfix. please accept as the answer if it works for you. facepalm on the "hacky" though. Inline style is actually "hacky". Putting your style in the head is much better practice, second only to putting it in an external file.

Comment: That did it for me, thanks! Isn't inline styling the "Angular way" of adding styling? I know that adding a new file for your styling is the way to go usually but I've never seen anybody do the on an Angular project but that might just be because I'm a noob and everybody around me might be too haha